# How do I transfer VST plugins from FL Studio to Ableton Live?

Tags: ableton-live, vst, ableton, fl-studio, plugins

So far, I've tried creating a new folder for VST plugins and filling it with the plugins I have from FL studio, and changing the source folder in Ableton to that folder, to no avail. Any suggestions? Also, I downloaded Max for Ableton Live but an unable to access it through Ableton. Any help for these two issues is much appreciated.

Comment: So, you can scan the folder, but if you hold a key (i think shift) and press scan, it will force scan everything in the folder. That's just something cheap to try for now. And.... you have "use VST plug-in custom folder" set to ON right?

Answer (score 2):

Start Ableton Live and go to the Preferences > File/Folder. 
Put **all your vst plugins** in one folder and scan it, unlike fl studio that allows you to scan multiple folders.

Comment: How will it work for plugins that reside in their own folders? Should the `.dll` file be in that one library, with all the data still in plugin's own folder?

Comment: @bipll Yeah that would work.

Answer (score 2):

### Method 1: Buy plugins as VST

Not all FL plugins will work on outside of FL. Cause they are FL only plugins. You have to purchase them from image line separately to use outside of FL. Go to  [Image line plugin page](https://www.image-line.com/plugins/category/all/), check  if it is available as VST, some available as Audio Unit too. You will see windows, apple logo next to the name, or VST icon in each plugins details.

### Method 2: Rewire

[Rewire](https://www.image-line.com/support/FLHelp/html/rewire_client.htm) Fl studio in [Ableton](https://www.image-line.com/support/FLHelp/html/rewire_client_live.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Use Voicemeeter to digitally send audio from Ableton to FL, run FL Studio as a VST within Ableton; from there you can save the audio within FL, export WAV, and import into Ableton [OR you could setup an additional in/out within Voicemeeter and patch post audio back into Ableton (possible latency)]